# Flutter: What am I doing that is causing a bug where a provider variable is changing whenever another provider variable is changed?

Tags: flutter, android-widget, flutter-provider, state-management

I have a bug that I cannot track down. Whenever I update a variable in my Provider class, it updates another with the same value. I have a widget that allows for selection of multiple menu items, and I am working on having a save feature, and a discard feature. I am calling the function that should reset all currently selected indices if back arrow is pressed, and this is functional for the first execution, however, if I edit the currently selected options, the saved indices change whenever the currently selected indices are changed. Hopefully the code makes sense, as I cut a significant amount out, to leave the most important in.

Provider class:

```
class ItemProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<int> _defaultSelectedFlavorsIndices = [];
  List<int> _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices = [];
  List<int> _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices = [];

  List<int> get defaultSelectedFlavorsIndices => _defaultSelectedFlavorsIndices;
  List<int> get currentSelectedFlavorsIndices => _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices;
  List<int> get savedSelectedFlavorsIndices => _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices;

  void updateCurrentSelectedFlavorsIndices(int index) {
    if (_currentSelectedFlavorsIndices.contains(index)) {
      _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices.remove(index);
    } else {
      _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices.add(index);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearSelectionHistory() {
    _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices = _defaultSelectedFlavorsIndices;
  }

  void discardCurrentFlavors() {
    _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices = _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateSavedIndices() {
    _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices = _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices;
  }

  bool changesWereMade() {
    return listEquals(_currentSelectedFlavorsIndices, _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices);
  }
}
```

second_screen.dart:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final itemProvider = Provider.of<ItemProvider>(context);
    Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
      bool? shouldPop;
      if (itemProvider.changesWereMade() == false) {
        shouldPop = true;
      } else {
        shouldPop = await showDialog<bool>(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Center(child: Text('Are you sure?')),
              content: const Text(
                  "If you cancel now, all of your customization will be lost"),
              actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Yes'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, false);
                  },
                  child: const Text('No'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
      if (shouldPop!) {
        // works on first execution
        itemProvider.discardCurrentFlavors();
      }
      return shouldPop;
    }

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => onWillPop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: items.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ItemOptionTile(
                      value: index,
                      groupValues: itemProvider.currentSelectedFlavorsIndices,
                      imagePath: "pictures/item.png",
                      onChanged: () {
                        itemProvider
                            .updateCurrentSelectedFlavorsIndices(index);
                      },
                      title: items[index]['name']);
                },
                separatorBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return const Divider(thickness: 1);
                },
              ),
            ),
            CancelSaveButtons(
              onWillPop: () => onWillPop(),
              onSave: () => itemProvider.updateSavedIndices(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

item_option_tile.dart:

```
class ItemOptionTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  final List<int> groupValues;
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback onChanged;
  final String imagePath;
  final int calories;

  const itemOptionTile(
      {Key? key,
      required this.value,
      required this.groupValues,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.title,
      this.calories = 0,
      this.imagePath = ""})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = this.title;
    final isSelected = groupValues.contains(value);
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: const Color(0xFFFFCB05),
      onTap: () => onChanged(),
      child: Container(
        height: 65,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(imagePath),
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    calories != 0
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                            child: Text("$calories cal."),
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            isSelected
                ? const Icon(Icons.check_circle_rounded,
                    color: Color(0xFFE02A27))
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of this `   final itemProvider = Provider.of<ItemProvider>(context);` wrap your widget with a consumer widget .